Use of the dative case after the preposition "от"
In Братья Карамазовы by Dostoevsky I read:

Это она от страху уверена, что выздоровеет.

Why not "от страха" instead of "от страху"? I thought that "от" was followed by the genitive case and not the dative. When should we use the dative case after "от"?

This is a variation of the genitive, sometimes referred to as "the second genitive" (второй родительный) or "the partitive" (количественно-отделительный).
For the most part, it's used to mark an unspecified quantity of uncountable nouns: выпить чаю, купить сахару etc. It's strongly preferred for the nouns formed with the diminutive suffix -ок: попить чайку, добавить чесночку (not *чайка, *чесночка).
This case used to be also sometimes used instead of the regular genitive with the prepositions от, без, c, like in your example, especially when от or с were used in the sense of "because":


В это время, когда даже у занимающих высшие должности болит от морозу лоб и слезы выступают в глазах, бедные титулярные советники иногда бывают беззащитны. [Н. В. Гоголь. Шинель (1842)]
Они гибли не от нее, а от голоду и усталости... " [Д. В. Давыдов. Мороз ли истребил французскую армию в 1812 году? (1830-1835)]


These days, this usage  has significantly declined, and for the most part remains in set expressions like час о́т часу, бе́з году неделя, о́т роду, с голоду etc.

Я бы ещё добавил про локативное (аблативное?) значение, хотя, не будучи русистом, не уверен в корректной формулировке грамматической функции. Я о словосочетаниях типа «из лесу», «из дому», «с возу» и т.п.
